# What is 'to be polite' in this sentence? Is it an object?

Tags: sentence-structure

What is *'to be polite'* in this sentence?

> *"The student is taught **to be polite**."*

What is its use and what is it called?

Answer (score 1):

This is a sentence with a verb (*teach*), a direct object (*what* is being taught) and an indirect object (*who* it is being taught *to*). Because it's a passive form, the **indirect object** (*the student*) has become the subject of the sentence. The thing which is being taught (being polite) is still the **direct object**.

If you're asking about the structure of *teach to be polite*, it's just a verb + infinitive (and an adjective because it's *be*). It's a common structure with certain verbs - *I hate to do this*, *I want to believe*, *you like to dance* etc. *Teach* usually takes an indirect object (*who* is being taught), so normally you'd have that in the middle (*can you teach **me** to drive?*) but because this example is passive, that indirect object is moved.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't understand your question at first.
In your sentence, **'polite'** is an *adjective*, which qualifies the *noun*, **'student'**. And, **'to be polite'** is a *to-infinitive* form of the word **polite**.

Comment: So is it an indirect object?